# how to use nested for loop with on_parent in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

i want to make nested for loop in kivy language by using `on_perent` then i try the slashes but there is error invalid indentation must be a multiple of 4 spaces i don't know what to do and there is no other than slashes

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:import Button kivy.uix.button.Button
BoxLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        on_parent:for i in range(2):\n \t \b\b\b\b\b \
        on_parent:for i in range(3):\n \t \
        on_parent:self.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))
''')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: can you share your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way of doing the nested for loop but I don't understand what you are trying to achieve

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:import Button kivy.uix.button.Button
BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
                on_parent:
                        if not self.children: [self.add_widget(Button(text=str(j))) for i in range(2) for j in range(3)]
''')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: You work is good but I try to make treeview just in the kivy language because it easy to read but your work not helping me because I have more than nested loop in for loop I have some function in every loop

Comment: something like this? https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.treeview.html

Comment: Yes but just in kivy language but just to know it needs nested for loop

Comment: This link is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/68088654/16271811